# Javascript regular expression matching prior and trailing characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string in a object:

```
<FLD>dsfgsdfgdsfg;NEW-7db5-32a8-c907-82cd82206788</FLD><FLD>dsfgsdfgsd;NEW-480e-e87c-75dc-d70cd731c664</FLD><FLD>dfsgsdfgdfsgfd;NEW-0aad-440a-629c-3e8f7eda4632</FLD>
```

`this.model.get('value_long').match(/[<FLD>\w+;](NEW[-|\d|\w]+)[</FLD>]/g)`

Returns:

```
[";NEW-7db5-32a8-c907-82cd82206788<", ";NEW-480e-e87c-75dc-d70cd731c664<", ";NEW-0aad-440a-629c-3e8f7eda4632<"]
```

What is wrong with my regular expression that it is picking up the preceding `;` and trailing `<`

here is a link to the regex 
http://regexr.com?30k3m

Updated:

this is what I would like returned:

```
["NEW-7db5-32a8-c907-82cd82206788", "NEW-480e-e87c-75dc-d70cd731c664", "NEW-0aad-440a-629c-3e8f7eda4632"]
```

here is a JSfiddle for it

http://jsfiddle.net/mwagner72/HHMLK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets create a character class, which you do not want here, try changing your regex to the following:

```
<FLD>\w+;(NEW[-\d\w]+)</FLD>
```

Since it looks like you want to grab the capture group from each match, you can use the following code to construct an array with the capture group in it:

```
var regex = /<FLD>\w+;(NEW[\-\d\w]+)<\/FLD>/g;
var match = regex.exec(string);
var matches = [];
while (match !== null) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(string);
}
```

`[<FLD>\w+;]` would match one of the characters inside of the square brackets, when I think what you actually want to do is match all of those.  Also for the other character class, `[-|\d|\w]`, you can remove the `|` because it is already implied in a character class, `|` should only be used for alternation inside of a group.

Here is an updated link with the new regex: http://jsfiddle.net/RTkzx/1

Comment: And I believe he will want to grab the first capturing group.  Seems to be trying to strip the beginning and end stuff off.

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I have looked at the link, however your regex is not matching the correct sections of the string.

Comment: @MarkWagner  See my edit, I think it should now do what you want.  I also included a JSfiddle link.